# Batch Q: How can I loop through all FindStr results and present it as a menu?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

Thanks for you time! This probably won't be a challenge for you.

So I have a list that is a txt file with the format ######.NAME-DATE which corresponds to files. The ##'s are unique identifying numbers, with the date representing different files for the same number. I want to have a batch file ask for the number and find all the files corresponding to that number and present this as a menu so the user can choose which she/he wants to open.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off   
set /p Input=Enter MRN:

set var=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "%Input%" log.txt') do (
    set var=!var!%%a"|"
    SET /A COUNT += 1
)    
set var=!var!
endlocal

PAUSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Would you consider a Powershell solution?  It's fairly easy to create a menu prompt with the built-in Out-GridView.  `powershell -c "Select-String %input% '%cd%\log.txt' | Out-GridView -PassThru | % { echo $_.Line }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

set /p Input=Enter MRN:

for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i /b /n /L "%Input%" q28574900.txt') do (
 set "$%%a=%%b"
)
SET "selection="
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims==:" %%a in ('set $ 2^>nul^|findstr /n /r "^"') do (
 ECHO %%a : %%c
 SET /a selection=%%a
)
IF NOT DEFINED selection ECHO no matches&GOTO :eof
SET "selection="
SET /p "selection=Select which ? "
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims==:" %%a in ('set $ 2^>nul^|findstr /n /r "^"') do (
 IF "%selection%"=="%%a" SET "selection=%%c"&GOTO run
)
ECHO invalid selection
GOTO :eof

:run
ECHO run whatever using %selection%


GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28574900.txt` containing some filename data for my testing. (woud have been better if you'd provided a sample)

First, select names according to `input`, but with the `/b` switch (to match at beginning of line) `/L` for literal-match `/i` for case-insensitive (in case you want alpha-match too)  and  `/n` to provide `a unique number:` at the start of the line. Having first cleared out all `$` variables, set `$uniquenumber` to the filename found.

Display the menu by running all the values of `set $` through a `findstr /n /r`. The lies would be of the form `3: $3=filename3` so delimit on `:` and `=` and show the first and third tokens. UUse `selection` as a flag (if set, 1 or more files found - can use the fact that if `selection` is `1` at the end to auto-run if desired)

Then ask for a selection and match the selection made to the list using the same method as used to display the menu. If you find the selection made, set the filename in `selection` and run the required program, if not, report the problem and finish.

Note that if you enter "12" as `input` then all files starting `12` will be displayed. If you want to match including the **<kbd>.</kbd>** then append `.` to `%input%` in the first `findstr`.